# How to compare different database table column and adding in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different databases, the same column. I want to copy the pictures from the old database to the new database by comparing the numbers between the tables and having the same number.

For example:

Database name 1: `StudentInformation`, table name: `Student`

```
StudentID     Image
---------------------
  123         1.png    
  142         2.png    
  175         3.png    
  475         4.png
```

Database name 2: `StudentInformation2`, table name: `NewStudent`

```
 StudentID       Image
 --------------------------
  145            a14.png    
  196            7.png    
  175            5.png    
  875            9.png    
  475            12.png
```

The two tables have common IDs (ID=175 and ID=475)

I want to get this table as a result:

```
StudentID    Image
-----------------------
  145        a14.png    
  196          7.png    
  175          3.png    
  875          9.png    
  475          4.png
```

I wrote this query:

```
INSERT INTO NEW STUDENT 
    SELECT STUDENT ID 
    FROM STUDENT 
    WHERE STUDENT INFORMATION1.STUDENT ID = STUDENT INFORMATION2.STUDENTID
```

But it doesn't run. How do I write SQL to add images to common ID columns by comparing the old table with the ID values of the new table?

Comment: You can try to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`

Comment: Is the dash (`-`) character in the second sample standing in for `NULL`, or do you really have a dash there?

Comment: Hi.This value can be any value or may be null.What is important is that this common field receives the first table value.

Comment: @K.E Okay. I altered your sample data so that information is evident from the data. Now we can clearly see ID 175 already had an Image value in the new table, but the desired result used the value from the old table.

Comment: If the first table and the second table should be the same as the values of the first table and the values of the first table should be the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want an `UPDATE`, that changes existing rows, not an `INSERT`, which created new rows. For that, you can use a correlated subquery, to get the image of the old table with the shared ID. To make sure to only update rows where a row in the old table exists, use a correlated subquery with `EXISTS`. Otherwise you'd set the images of rows, where no old record exists to `NULL`.

```
UPDATE studentinformation2.dbo.newstudent
       SET image = (SELECT student.image
                           FROM studentinformation.dbo.student
                           WHERE student.studentid = newstudent.studentid)
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM studentinformation.dbo.student
                            WHERE student.studentid = newstudent.studentid);
```

I assumed the schema of the tables is `dbo` in both databases. If that's not the case you have to change the schema identifiers to reflect the actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

*It's not clear whether the `-` value in the second sample is really that character in the data, or if it's just standing in for `NULL`. In this answer, I assume the latter.*

---

The first thing to understand is *you can't leave the spaces in the table and column names.* Best not to use spaces in table and column names at all, but if you must, you have to at least enclose those names in square brackets, ie: `[NEW STUDENT]`.

Next, you already have data for StudentID values 175 and 475, so *this will not be an INSERT command at all*. It will be an **UPDATE** command.

Now, assuming the databases are on the same server or that a linked server already exists, and your connection has the needed privileges to both databases, you will have to *fully qualify* everything, including the schema (almost always `dbo`).

Put all that together, and you get this:

```
UPDATE n /* n = new, o = old */
SET n.Image = o.Image
FROM StudentInformation2.dbo.NewStudent n
INNER JOIN StudentInformation.dbo.Student o ON o.StudentID = n.StudentID
-- removed WHERE clause based on a comment to the question. The o
--WHERE n.Image IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using microsoft sql server you can use for inserting new data with this

```
INSERT INTO NEW_STUDENT (ID,Image)
SELECT student.ID, stundet.Image
FROM STUDENT left join NEW_STUDENT on NEW_STUDENT.StundetID = Student.ID
where newstudent.ID is null
```

and for updating data use this

```
update newstudent set id = student.id,image = student.image
SELECT student.ID, stundet.Image
FROM STUDENT inner join NEW_STUDENT on NEW_STUDENT.StundetID = Student.ID
```